# Why am I getting a "missing field" error using config-rs?

Tags: rust, config, toml

I'm confused why I am getting an `Err(missing field "web3_node_provider")` error when I `cargo run` using config-rs. Appears to fail at `s.try_deserialize()`:

```
use config::{Config, ConfigError, Environment, File};
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[allow(unused)]
struct Web3NodeProvider {
    ethereum_mainnet_node_url_http: String,
    alchemy_api_key: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[allow(unused)]
pub struct Settings {
    web3_node_provider: Web3NodeProvider,
}

impl Settings {
    pub fn new() -> Result<Self, ConfigError> {
        let s = Config::builder()
            .add_source(File::with_name("config/default"))
            .add_source(File::with_name("config/local").required(false))
            .add_source(Environment::with_prefix("app"))
            .build()?;
        s.try_deserialize()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let settings = Settings::new();
    println!("{:?}", settings);
}
```

I've pretty much followed the [hierarchy example](https://github.com/mehcode/config-rs/blob/master/examples/hierarchical-env/settings.rs) in config-rs, so I'm sure I'm just misunderstanding something basic or missing something. I am able to use `"Web3NodeProvider.url"` but not `"web3_node_provider.ethereum_mainnet_node_url_http"`.

default.toml

```toml
[Web3NodeProvider]
ethereum_mainnet_node_url_http = "https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/"
alchemy_api_key = "alchemy-api-key"
```

local.toml

```toml
[Web3NodeProvider]
alchemy_api_key = "randomapikey"
```

Comment: it's hard to say without looking at your config file actually. It says "missing field", so very likely your config file is missing that information

Comment: @NikolayZakirov I've updated my question. You think it's because I'm missing `web3_node_provder` in the Toml files?

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: @NikolayZakirov just updated right now, but I've tried adding it in the toml files and still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [example](https://github.com/mehcode/config-rs/blob/master/examples/hierarchical-env/config/default.toml), you have to name your field in config as name of attribute not name of structure (type). Like so:

```toml
[web3_node_provider]
ethereum_mainnet_node_url_http = "https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/"
alchemy_api_key = "alchemy-api-key"
```

Comment: thank you for this--works now! 

I'm not sure I fully understand why this is the case, but I appreciate you!

Comment: @Alex, you have to match the field name, not the type name. The part before the `:` not after in this `web3_node_provider: Web3NodeProvider` the same way you don't use `String` for this `alchemy_api_key: String`